# How to hide options from a drop down menu search that won't find anything? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, drop-down-menu, django-templates

The website filter is implemented with three drop-down menus(color, model, engine), each has its own list of options. I need to hide color/model/engine  options that won't give any results(i.e. not found| response.items.length == 0).

The website runs on Django, so the initial color/model/engine that are loaded are already filtered with views.py to a degree, meaning they don't have options that don't have any variations regardless of the other two selections. Meaning if, for example, for color RED there are no results, regardless of the other options, color RED isn't loaded(filtered in views.py).

However, if, let's say, for color RED, there are only models with the "A" engine, and no models with the "B" engine, my question is, how do I hide the "B" option from the engine drop-down menu when RED is selected? And vice-versa, if the "B" engine has no RED variation, how do I hide RED from the color drop-down menu when "B" is selected?

The color listing part looks like this:

```
                <div class="select-color__items">
                   {% for color in colors %}
                    <label for="{{ color|slice:"1:" }}" style="background-color: {{ color }}" class="select-color__item js-color-item js-select-filter  {% if color == "#ffffff" %}select-color__item_white{% endif %}">
                    <input type="radio" id="{{ color|slice:"1:" }}" name="color" {% if request.GET.color == color|slice:"1:" %}  checked="checked" {% endif %} value="{{ color|slice:"1:" }}"/>
                  </label>
                  {% endfor %}
                 <div class="select-color__all-wrapp">
                    <label for="all" class="select-color__all open js-color-item js-select-filter">
                      {{ '__CATALOG-ALL__'|translate_value:LANGUAGE_CODE }}
                      <input type="radio" id="all" name="color" value="all"/>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

The updateFilter Javascript function looks like this:

```
function updateFilter(data) {
    var form_data = data.$form.serializeArray();
    form_data.push({name: 'url', value: urlPath + '?' + data.$form.find(":input:not([name=csrfmiddlewaretoken],[name=category])").serialize()});
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.post({
            data: form_data,
            url: data.url,
            success: function (response) {
                ChangeUrl( 'Title test' , response['url'] );
                data.callback(response)
            }
        });
    }, 100);
}
```

The response has the new items, that have been found with the selected (color, model, engine) options. Do I actually need to make similar requests for every option in the other two drop down-menus and then filter out based on response.items.length? That's the only solution I came up with and it will work, but it just feels so huge and ineffective.